# BGE Actions not working to the rig [any of the other questions helped]

Tags: animation, game-engine, rigging, armature, logic-bricks

I'm quite new at BGE and recently downloaded [this rig](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/76261), which is my main character. I built the animations in the action editor but when applying in the logic editor it doesn't seem to work.
I actually changed some things I thought could help: No mirror modifier, deform set to BGE, joined the skin with the clothes.
Here are quick topics of what I've already tried doing:
-add a cube and parent it to the rig
-apply the action to the rigid body
-tried merging everything but couldn't 

[image: my outliner rn]

Also, it has an armature modifier and if I apply it, the rig won't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First aid:

- un-parent skin mesh object from armature object
- ensure the skin mesh object has no modifiers at that state
- parent the skin mesh object to the armature object in deform mode
- ensure the skin mesh has vertex groups matching the bone names
- ensure you have an animation (action) that belongs to the armature
- add logic bricks that activate an Action actuator playing your animation in-game
- start the BGE and activate the above logic

E.g.

Always -> AND -> Action Actuator